# Finding min + 1 in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Hi guys i have a postgres table with a column for event and a column for sequence. Every event may have multiple sequences. For ex:

```
Event  |   Sequence
a      |    1
a      |    4
a      |    5
b      |    1
b      |    2
```

Now i know that select min(sequence) group by event gives me the minimum sequence. How do i get the very next value after the min value. i hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.
I'm Using Postgres 9.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` partitioning by `Event` and ordering by `Sequence` to get the second lowest sequence number per Event;

```
SELECT Event, Sequence 
FROM (
  SELECT Event, Sequence, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Event ORDER BY Sequence) rn
  FROM Table1
) z
WHERE rn = 2;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4438b/1).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** A bit more complicated, but if you need a query that doesn't rely on `ROW_NUMBER()`, use a subquery with a self-join to exclude rows with minimum sequence for each event:

```
SELECT outer_query.Event, MIN(outer_query.Sequence) AS SecondMinSeq
FROM Table1 as outer_query
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Table1.Event, MIN(Sequence) AS MinSeq
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Table1.Event
) AS min_sequences
ON outer_query.Event = min_sequences.Event AND outer_query.Sequence <> min_sequences.MinSeq
GROUP BY outer_query.Event
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4438b/7

Comment: what if sequences are not in order..for example if a had sequences 1,3,7,11 etc then how do i select the second most minimum sequence..Hope that makes more sense..